# Extract multiple codes from cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

I was wondering if any one could help me. I have a list of elements (journal articles) and I have a column with categories. Each of these cells contains a classification, based on a description and an id. Moreover, there are cells that contains multiples codes.The delimiters are very different (sometimes commas, semicolon...). I want to extract the ids (e.g. J32, E59...) but I don't know how to do it. See below an example:

[image]

The output I want obtain (see Result column) is the following:

[image]

My first attempt was to separate text to columns but the delimiters are different. I also have tried searching for the codes (with FIND because I have a list) but I do not know how to do it with multiples codes.

Any suggestion would be very valuable! Thanks in advance,

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Excel 2019 or Excel O365?

Comment: Excel 2019 (but I can download O365 easily!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got Excel2019/O365, here is what you could use:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,";",","),","," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()=3][substring(., 2,2)*0=0][translate(substring(.,1,1),'JEF','')='']"))
```

- `SUBSTITUTE` is there to change the possible delimiters. Add more if need be.
- The three `XPATH` expressions used could be interpreted as some sort of regular expression, making sure that we select element that are: Thee characters long, the last two characters are digits and the first character is upper-case J, E or F. Add more if need be.
- `TEXTJOIN` will add all returned elements back together using a comma.

---

Another option for other versions of Excel would be an UDF where you could make use of actual regular expressions. For example through pattern:

```
\b[JEF]\d\d\b
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/a4EFYY/1) online demo for an example.

Comment: @EmmanuelleCrayon, did it work for you? If so, please consider to mark as answered.